# Why can't I delete the 'view' outlet of a UITableViewController in the connection inspector in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, connection

So I am trying to re-write some code from objective c to swift and in my view controller connection inspector, a connection appeared that I can't explain.

I tried to go through my code and I don't see any obvious invalid outlets set up. What else could be causing the following greyed connection to appear?

[image: ![Screen shot of view connection that can't be deleted.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal behavior for the default view of a UITableViewController in Interface Builder. If you look at the XML of your Storyboard, UITableViewControllers are represented by a special tag - `<tableViewController>`. Xcode automatically assigns its `view` outlet and does not allow you to change it through Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. The Storyboard handle this outlet automatically.